# How do I get a Canon PIXMA MX350 working on 64 bit?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, printing, canon, pixma

Anybody successful on installing this printer on amd64 please?

Canon supplies 32bit drivers -- as *.deb and also as source: http://www.canon.com.au/en-au/For-You/Printers/PIXMA-InkJet-Printers/MX350  Current compilation failed ...  Trying to install the i386 debian packages worked somehow ...

as of 2011-11 there's an awesome ppa repository:

[How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-driver)

Comment: you should move much of your question into an answer so you can accept it.  Well done.  Upvote from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know why, but I can print now -- also wireless.

- once supplied the PPD from the canon driver source archive, but deleted the printer again as it complained about missing filter
- tried to compile source as stated above
- tried to force install of i386 packages as above
- added the printer once again and it found it as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

---

Even scanning works!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` package? That's what I need for my printer on 64 bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, trying to force the i366 .deb is prevented by some unmet dependencies -- added output above. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

My MX350 on 11.04 wasn't working either.  I had ia32-libs installed, but the install of cnijfilter-common_3.30-1_i386.deb still complained of missing i386 deps.  I tried manually installing a few but they were already present.  So I went ahead and added the "--force-depends" option

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture --force-depends cnijfilter-common_3.30-1_i386.deb
```

and re-added the printer, and everything seems to be working fine.