# How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?

Tags: printing, canon

I tried to install the MP190 drivers, but appeared a message show me that requires to have libcupsys2. I understand that libcup2 is an update of libcupsys2.

How do I solve this? Are there proprietary drivers for my Canon printer or scanner?

Comment: Sorry to revive this thread.
I've managed to get the 2 drivers installed from the ppa for raring. I've also got printing working fine even via network.
However, I can get the scanning function to work. scangearmp installs fine but it comes up saying it cannot find a scanner both via usb and network. Is there some file I can edit so that I can tell scangearmp where to look for the scanner? Xsane doesn't find it either.
BTW, if i type "scanimage -L" i get a response to say there is a scanner available.

Comment: For any Canon printer see this answer (also works for Ubuntu 20.04):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261887/canon-g1010-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04/1294113#1294113

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### PPA

I found the solution!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk  
sudo apt-get update
```

for older releases use `ppa:michael-gruz/canon`.

Finally,

`sudo apt-get install [model]`

### Printer

Where [model] would be for:

Canon Pixma iP Series Ubuntu driver

```
Canon iP100 Ubuntu Driver -  cnijfilter-ip100series
Canon iP1800 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip1800series
Canon iP1000 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixmaip1000series
Canon iP1500 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixmaip1500series
Canon iP1900 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip1900series
Canon iP 2200 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip2200series
Canon iP2500 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip2500series
Canon iP2600 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip2600series
Canon iP2700 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip2700series
Canon iP3300 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip3300series
Canon iP3500 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip3500series
Canon iP3600 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip3600series
Canon iP4200 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip4200series
Canon iP4500 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip4500series
Canon iP4700 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip4700series
Canon iP4800 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip4800series
Canon iP5200 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip5200series
Canon iP6600 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip6600series
Canon iP7500 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-ip7500series
```

Canon Pixma MG Series Ubuntu Driver

```
Canon MG5100 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mg5100series
Canon MG5200 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mg5200series
Canon MG6100 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mg6100series
Canon MG8100 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mg8100series
```

Canon PIXMA MP Series Ubuntu Driver

```
Canon MP140 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp140series
Canon MP160 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp160series
Canon MP190 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp190series
Canon MP210 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp210series
Canon MP240 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp240series
Canon MP490 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp490series
Canon MP500 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp500series
Canon MP510 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp510series
Canon MP520 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp520series
Canon MP540 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp540series
Canon MP550 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp550series
Canon MP560 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp560series
Canon MP600 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp600series
Canon MP610 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp610series
Canon MP630 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp630series
Canon MP640 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mp640series
```

Canon MX Series Ubuntu Driver

```
Canon MX320 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx320series
Canon MX330 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx330series
Canon MX350 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx350series
Canon MX360 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx360series
Canon MX410 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx410series
Canon MX420 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx420series
Canon MX860 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx860series
Canon MX870 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx870series
Canon MX880 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-mx880series
```

Canon PIXUS Series Ubuntu Driver

```
Pixus 550 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixus5510iseries
Pixus 560 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixus560iseries
Pixus 850 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixus850iseries
Pixus 860 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixus860iseries
Pixus 865 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixus865iseries
Pixus 950 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixus950iseries
Pixus 990 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixus990iseries
Canon Pixus ip3100 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixusip3100series
Canon Pixus ip4100 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixusip4100series
Canon Pixus ip8600 Ubuntu Driver - cnijfilter-pixusip8600series
```

Reference: http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/06/download-install-canon-printer-driver.html

### Scanner

If you would like to download the **scanner application** (and driver) install one of these packages (according to your model number):

```
scangearmp-mg5100series
scangearmp-mg5200series
scangearmp-mg6100series
scangearmp-mg8100series
scangearmp-mp140series
scangearmp-mp160series
scangearmp-mp190series
scangearmp-mp210series
scangearmp-mp240series
scangearmp-mp250series
scangearmp-mp270series
scangearmp-mp280series
scangearmp-mp490series
scangearmp-mp495series
scangearmp-mp510series
scangearmp-mp520series
scangearmp-mp540series
scangearmp-mp550series
scangearmp-mp560series
scangearmp-mp600series
scangearmp-mp610series
scangearmp-mp630series
scangearmp-mp640series
scangearmp-mx320series
scangearmp-mx330series
scangearmp-mx340series
scangearmp-mx350series
scangearmp-mx360series
scangearmp-mx410series
scangearmp-mx420series
scangearmp-mx860series
scangearmp-mx870series
scangearmp-mx880series
```

Then look for "Scan Gear MP" or run from the terminal:

```
scangearmp
```

Comment: My CanonMP610 printer works perfectly under 12.04 gnome classic, but only @ 600 dpi. I want to print photos. The above method worked for me (although I had to replace pangolin by oneiric in the PPA address), I can install the printer, select the printer in the print menu (of eg Firefox, Openoffice, whatever...), choose between different resolutions, up to more than 2000; the software says it's printing, notification bubbles tell me the print job started and ended, but, guess what... the printer stays dead...! Started a bounty, can anyone help, please?

Comment: I also want to add: the method suggested by Michael K doesn't work for me, there still is an unmet dependency (libpopt0:i386) that I don't seem to be able to install (ubuntu 12.04, gnome classic)

Comment: @Tinellus - I've sent an email to the PPA owner to whether he intends to create a Precise repo - if he responds I'll drop a comment for you here.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the effort... From some of the comments on 'ubuntubuzz' I see other people having similar problems on 12.04; I hope asking the ppa-owner once more will speed up things a bit...

Comment: My bounty is expiring and there are no answers... Can I award it to a comment, somehow?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package scangearmp-mp140series
can you help me with this?

Comment: this ppa does not appear to have any files for saucy...

Comment: ...nor for 14.04 :-/

Comment: The name of the ppa changed to `canon-trunk` but I did not update the list of supported printers.

Comment: support seems to stop at 14.10

Answer (score 12):

For 14.04 through 20.04 do the following:

1. Download the drivers from:
   https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/mf4770n?tab=drivers#Z7_MQH8HIC0L88RB0AMD0F1Q42K25
2. Extract the file archive to a directory. From that directory:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   tar -xf *inux_UFRII*.tar.*
   sudo dpkg -i *inux_UFRII*/*/Debian/*.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
3. It shouldn't be necessary to reboot, but if the next step fails, reboot and try again.
4. Run "Add printer". That should just show up automatically when you click the 'Add' button. Give it a few seconds and the printer chirps then just magically shows up.

EDIT 2/27/16 (16.04beta) Updated the link to the 3.10 driver (they updated their website). Everything just worked using above, didn't need to reboot.

EDIT 9/8/16: The current driver version is now 3.20. Make installation commands agnostic to both the driver version and the system architecture.

EDIT 06/12/20: The current driver version is now 5.10. Adjusted the installation steps for different wildcards.

Comment: @KarlRichter: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/595126/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... ;-)

Comment: I didn't give an answer, just edited one and don't see where the conflict with the editing help lies - please be more specific. I can't review your edits as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: The link must have changed. That page does not show drivers at all. You can click on a Support button which takes you to a drivers page. The site may autodetect Linux and display no drivers. If that happens, choose your version (32 or 64 bit) to see the drivers.

Comment: @revnoah thanks for the note. i updated the link to the driver page. i'll test with 3.10 and update steps if needed.

Comment: I'm still weirded out by American date formats…

Comment: Is this still working on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I just updated my driver as a test .... yes it still works.

Answer (score 4):

For many (but not all) Canon printers and scanners we can download a proprietary Linux driver from [Canon Asia](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/?personal). If a driver was not yet listed in the Canon web search tool linked above we may still find links to the appropriate driver downlaods from the [Canon product overview](http://www.canon.com.ph/PRODUCTS.aspx) page. Download the **Debian package archives** to install the proprietary printer drivers with the Ubuntu Software Center by a double click on them.

The proprietary scanner application **scangearmp** will not install with SANE and hence can not be used with applications based on SANE. After installation is it run from the terminal:

```
scangearmp
```

Note that drivers available there support a series of printers but not a subset of of this series. This is usually indicated by the product numbering (e.g. for a Pixma IP 2820 you will download the driver for the IP2800 series, for a PIXMA MX457 you will need the driver for the MX450 series, etc.)

Older drivers may also be available from **ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk**.

Some Canon printers are also supported by the [Gutenprint](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gutenprint) drivers. Borderless or high resolution photo-printing may not be supported.

You may note that these drivers allow printing but they usually will not fully support all printer features. This has been like that for all Canon printers for reasons only Canon knows of.

In case we need a driver that fully supports all printer features there is a commercially available printer driver [Turboprint](http://www.turboprint.info/) which actually works great but you may not want to support their rather weird and expensive licencing plan (starting from $34 for one computer and two printers with free updates for 6 months only).

Answer (score 2):

libcupsys2 is a virtual package in 11.10 which installs libcups2. Maybe the canon driver (it is a proprietary driver i guess) checks for this package. You could install this meta-package doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libcupsys2
```

This should not install anything new, but mark the package itself as installed.

Then install the package using the following command:

```
dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libcupsys2 foo.deb
```

(Replace foo.deb by the package of the driver)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still have the same problem. Despite I install libcupsys2, the drivers show me a dependency problem.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the messages into your posting pls?

Comment: okay, i edited my post, hope this works, else, just comment on here again

Comment: Sorry, I was able to install it, but when I try to install other packages, first I must repair dependencies and drivers are uninstalled

Answer (score 2):

you may have to use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
```

I did. And the printer works fine.

Comment: thanks, worked for me on 12.04 (`ppa:michael-gruz/canon` did not)

Answer (score 1):

For newer Versions (I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04) it might be possible to simply use the GUI to add the Printer so check that out first (Printers -> Add -> ...).

If that does not work try executing the `install.sh`-Script if it is included in the driver `.tar.gz`-file of your driver (can be downloaded from the Canon Website, Section `Drivers`). Afterwards try adding the printer from the GUI again, that's what I just did and it works perfectly.

If that does not work, some of the other answers seem to work with newer versions of Ubuntu as well - so you might give that a try as well :) Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 20.10:

1. Install the `printer-driver-gutenprint` package:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
   ```
2. Open System Settings → *Printers*, and having selected your printer, the list of drivers should now be a lot more comprehensive!

   [image: Add a New Printer - driver selection (Kubuntu 20.10)]

Comment: this one worked for me for Canon MG3150 on Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this from http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/ :

> ...
>
> A third-party ppa contains the driver and scangear for commonly used Canon printers, available for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and its derivatives, such as Linux Mint 17.
>
> Below devices are supported:
>
> - bjf9000, bjf900, bjs300, bjs500, bjs700 series
> - e500, e510, e600, e610 series
> - i250, i255, i550, i560, i850, i860, i950, i990 series
> - ip100, ip1800, ip1900, ip2200, ip2500, ip2600, ip2700, ip3000, ip3300, ip3500, ip3600, ip4000, ip4200, ip4300, ip4500, ip4600, ip4700, ip4800, ip4900, ip5000, ip5200, ip6600, ip7200, ip7500, ip8500, ip90 series
> - ix6500 series
> - mg2100, mg2200, mg3100, mg3200, mg4100, mg4200, mg5100, mg5200, mg5300, mg5400, mg6100, mg6200, mg6300, mg8100, mg8200 series.
> - mp140, mp160, mp190, mp210, mp230, mp240, mp250, mp270, mp280, mp490, mp495, mp500, mp510, mp520, mp540, mp550, mp560, mp600, mp610, mp620, mp630, mp640, mp750, mp780 series.
> - mx320, mx330, mx340, mx350, mx360, mx370, mx390, mx410, mx420, mx430, mx450, mx510, mx520, mx710, mx720, mx860, mx870, mx880, mx890, mx920 series.
> - pixmaip1000, pixmaip1500 series.
> - pixus250, pixus255, pixus550, pixus560, pixus850, pixus860, pixus950, pixus990 series
> - pixusip3100, pixusip4100, pixusip8600 series
>
> Install Canon Drivers / ScanGear in Ubuntu 14.04:
>
> 1. To get started, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on keyboard to open terminal. When it opens, the command below and hit enter to run:
>
>    ```
>      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inameiname/stable
>    ```
>
> Type in your user password when it asks and hit Enter to continue. This will add the PPA repository into your system.
>
> 2. After that, open Synaptic Package Manager from the Unity Dash. If you don’t find it, search for and install it from Ubuntu Software Center.
>
> Do:
>
> - Click the Reload button to refresh your system cache.
>
>   - To install a printer driver:
>           In Quick filter box, type in `cnijfilter`.
>   - To install a ScanGear:
>           In Quick filter box, type in `scangearmp`.
> - Select a package in the result list that matches your device.
> - Right-click on the package and select “Mark for Installation”
> - Finally click on the “Apply” button to install the driver.
>
> Once the printer and scanner drivers are installed, connect your device to the computer and start Printers utility test if it works. And launch the Simple Scan utility and select your scanner from app menu Documents -> Preferences -> Scan Source to test if the scanner works.

Answer (score 0):

Canon MF212W:

1. go to page https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf212w.html?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)
   and select preferable system and language
2. go to Downloads and extract the file, something like

   ```
   tar xvzf linux-UFRII-drv-v570-m17n-13.tar.gz
   ```
3. go to directory with extracted files and run the install.sh

   ```
   cd linux-UFRII-drv-v570-m17n
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```

   It will ask you to add a driver with specific connection details, Like the printer's IP address.
4. Now you should have the option to use the printer.
   In my setup I use it wirelessly.