# How can I configure a Canon PIXMA MP780 printer?

Tags: 11.10, printing, canon

How can I get 11.10 desktop classic to configure Canon PIXMA MP780 printer on ubuntu.

New, clean install x86 desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the printer model wrong (now corrected to PIXMA MP780) and thanks to *itnet7* I found the correct repos(itory).

The steps I used to get this printer installed are these:

as from *itnet7* open a terminal and enter...

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon`

then...

`sudo apt-get update`

But for the MP780 which is not in michael-gruz repos, but the iP4100 is and from this ancient website

http://mambo.kuhp.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~takushi/

I learn that the iP4100 drivers work for the MP780, so...

`sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-pixusip4100series`

and then to get Ubuntu to recognize and configure the MP780, open a browser and use this URL...

`http://127.0.0.1:631/`

which should open CUPS 1.5.0 administration, click on `Adding Printers and Classes` then the `Add Printer` button...

Here you should see all local printers if they are connected and turned on.

Select the MP780 and "continue"...

Then fill in or change the printer information, &c, "Continue"...

Then select `Canon PIXMA MP780 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.7(en)` for the model, and finally press the "Add Printer" button....

Then You can set the default options and finally hit the button...

Ubuntu should pop up a message about the new printer and it should be shown in System Settings / Printers.

Good Luck!

Comment: Awesome!! Glad that you were able to get it working!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a PPA that contains your specific driver located [here.](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon) There is another question about installing another canon printer type that gave me the info found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-driver) for reference.

To save a bit of time here are the steps, you will need to add the following ppa using your preferred method. Here is a way to add it from the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then in your case you would want to install your printer using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mx870series
```

Here is the [resource](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/06/download-install-canon-printer-driver.html) the original question I have reference used.