# How do I get a Canon MP550 working with Gutenprint?

Tags: printing, canon

My printer canonMP550 doesn't work with i7 x86 64bit under Ubuntu 11.10 with
cups+Gutenprint2.5.7.  What I found, is: in gutenprint it is translated into ip4000
only, but it belongs to the group ip4700, which is translated into ip4300 (parameter).

I tried to correct, read only, what to do?

Next is gutenprint uses cups 1.2, but installed is cups 1.5 , so instead system/library/
color sync/ ..... it is `usr/share/color/icc/sRGB.icc`.

**So this seem to be real bugs**, but Ii am new and need help to correct this staff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to debug a Gutenprint driver (or any other printer driver) is not to be undertaken lightly...

However if you wish to work with the Cup developers the link that will help is:

- http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-other/cups-help.html

As an alternative suggestion, can I suggest you delete the Gutenprint driver.

There is a good PPA that several Ask Ubuntu Q&As recommend.

It has updated Canon Printer drivers - my suggestion is to use that PPA.  See the linked Q&A for installation instructions.

---

1. [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-driver)

Comment: Many thanks fossfreedom, now it is working. Only at 3. not the model but cnijfilter-mp550series!    Also still in cups the button search for usable printers does find nothing, it is there under the button printer adjustable.

Comment: Last question: have i to do something to let the "cups-people" know of this bugs? Also i spent now nearly two days frust with this, i would like, if others could avoid that frust,

Comment: There is a whole bunch of stuff to read here as well as mailing lists you can post stuff to:  http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-other/cups-help.html