# Added wireless printer for Canon MG8150 no print is produced

Tags: wireless, 11.10, printing, canon, pixma

On my new computer a 64 bits - I have a 64 bits Ubuntu 11.10 installed.
Adding network printer with settings for a generic MG8100 printer:

Location:   host-ip
Device URI: lpd://host-ip/LPT5
model:      Canon PIXMA MG8100 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.7 Simplified

When I tried to make a test print this happen:

1. Ubuntu send a print to the printer
2. The printer shows on the display that it is working
3. Ubuntu acknowledge with pop-up messages that print job was completed
4. The printer stop working on the display and nothing happens, no print is produced

There are no errors as far as I can see it.

Do anybody knows what to do, or what is wrong?

Remarks
On an old computer I have the Ubuntu 11.10 32 bits installed and the same printer connected with "Device URI: cnijet:/88-87-17-08-64-56" and that works fine on this computer. I tried to used that instead of the lpd setting on the new computer but then I got a cups client error.

I hope some body can help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried the 8100series printer driver from this PPA:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-driver

Comment: I found a solution as mention under answer but any way thank you for your comment I was looking at your link too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now succeeded in connecting the printer with correct driver by downloading the driver from canon home page http://software.canon-europe.com/. From there I selected the driver for PIXMA MG8150 and downloaded the file *MG8100series-printer_driver.tar*.

I extracted the folder *cnijfilter-mg8100series-3.40-1-deb*. In the folder I run the `install.sh` script and follow the instructions from there and now it works.