# How do I get a Canon Selphy ES1 printer working?

Tags: 10.10, printing, canon

My Canon Selphy ES1 photo printer does not work with Ubuntu 10.10
The printer is installed, and the print job is send to the printer, but nothing happens.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Canon Selphy ES1 is currently not supported in 10.10 [see wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersCanon)

Tested

There is a PPA with Canon drivers: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon
Read here how to use it:

[How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-mp190-driver)

http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-install-canon-pixma-mp-canon-mx.html

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/06/download-install-canon-printer-driver.html