# Does anyone know where to get printer drivers?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, lubuntu, printing, canon

Running lubuntu 12.04

My model is Canon IP4850, but anything resembling canon would be a good start. I didn't see anything looking remotely useful in the package manager.

Ideas?

Checked [for canon ip4800](http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/InkJet/PIXMA_iP_series/PIXMA_iP4850.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:14-822886&page=1&type=download) was down the way though.

Printer is detected but doesn't print.

**I managed to get it working by resetting it. Works fine on 12.04**

Comment: Canon website would be a good start.

Comment: you know you are too dependent on stack exchange when... I had tried that before and got nowhere, but you're right. it was there. I'll post the link!

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-mp190-driver. Unfortunately the ppa from the accepted answer seems not to work for 12.04 (but for 11.10).

Comment: ah that#s what i'm running. I got a driver from the site but yet to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about lubuntu, but in Ubuntu I didn't find my exact model when first installing.  I had to find a similar model and it worked perfectly.  I am not sure about your particular model, but look here.

You would just go into settings and then printers and add printer.  Perhaps you use Ubuntu to set it up and then switch back to Lubuntu.

Also you could just install the ppa as you saw in the comments.

https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon if it doesn't work please submit a bug, or let me know and I will.

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/06/download-install-canon-printer-driver.html

I would just find a related model with the same features and see if it works.  Most likely it would.  It did for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked fine on lunbuntu. Still need to do a bit of tweaking but nothing major. Thanks.