# Canon PIXMA MG2555, no drivers for Ubuntu

Tags: printing, canon

I recently got Canon PIXMA MG2555. I have Ubuntu 12.04LTS and there are no drivers for it. Is there any way I can make it work without a driver?
Cheers!

Comment: Have you actually tried to install the printer via system settings -> printer -> add printer? Any error message given?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon Printer MP190 driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-mp190-driver)

Answer (score 3):

Printers drivers for linux are available on [Canon website](http://www.canon.com/).

Download and install ScanGearMP and IJ Printer Driver.

- [Drivers for your printer can be found here.](http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG2550.aspx) (MG2550/2555)

Answer (score 1):

Installing `printer-driver-gutenprint` and then adding the printer again also does the job today.