# Simple Scan not recognizing Canon LiDE 25

Tags: usb, canon, scanner

I do `sane-find-scanner` and get:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x2220 [CanoScan]) at libusb:002:002
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
```

`scanimage -L` tells me:

> No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something
>   different, check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and
>   detected by the sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate).

The list of supported scanners says it is the same manpage as plustek.

My canon.conf file contains:

```
#canon.conf
#usb
[usb] 0x04a9 0x2220
device /dev/usbscanner
```

Anything else I should try ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver) see my answer there on how to install and use the proprietary Canon software (the scanner app `scangearmp` will not install a SANE driver).

Answer (score 0):

The scanner has been well supported earlier. At the moment he is no longer in the [list of supported devices](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON).

Here are some options:

- Fixed by disabling xHCI in BIOS ([CanoScan LiDE 25 not recognized? (Ubuntu 14.10)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253359))
- Works out of the box in Gutsy o_O ([Hardware Support Components Scanners Canon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersCanon))
- Try a shorter cable and don't use a USB hub ([Canon CanoScan LiDe 25 funktioniert nicht mehr mit SimpleScan](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/canon-canoscan-lide25-funktioniert-nicht-mehr-/))
- Fixed by disabling USB 3.0 and connect the scanner to existing USB 2.0 port ([Cannot scan using Canon Lide 25 with simple-scan on 14.04.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-scan/+bug/1384303))

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell optiplex with ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
I had the same problem with the sanner Canon Lide 25. I search a solution in different direction.

Finally, I have desactivated usb 3.0 in the bios (only using the 2.0 usb), and now the scanner works fine (with xsane or simple-scan) without any need to parametrize config files (just plug the scanner it works)!

Hope that it will  help someone

N.