# Install Canon MP560 Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: printing, canon

Trying to install a Canon PIXMA MP560 wireless printer on my brand new Ubuntu laptop:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Canon does not provide drivers for this printer. (I checked
[this link](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp560#DriversAndSoftware).)
Most of the answers point to a ppa that does not work for my OS.

For example, if I try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I get the error

> W: Failed to fetch
>   p://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   p://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

(In the above code, replace the p: with http:. I can't post more than 2 links without a 10 reputation.)

I looked at the 
[ppa repo](http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/) directly, and it seems that the latest version available is quantal.

I explicitly edited the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/michael-gruz-ubuntu-canon-vivid.list to point to quantal. That is, I replaced

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu vivid main
```

with

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu quantal main
```

That got rid of the update error, but I got a not found error when I tried to to the install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp560series
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-mp560series
```

It looks like the Package file for quantal (
ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages) is empty.

Any ideas? I guess I could try pointing to an even earlier version. Is there a better way to install this printer under Ubuntu 15?

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/a/586030/3940 - Canon Asia has more drivers available. You may have to download the driver for the MP568.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.04 seems to be not supported by this PPA – the latest change  was from 2014-06-23.

But you can download the matching packages from launchpad and try to install them manually.

As there seems to be no native 64 bit drivers support, you need to add the 32 bit architecture :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  
sudo apt-get update
```

Download and install the driver for **Canon PIXMA MP560 printer - printing functionality** :

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/cnijfilter-common-32_3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-common-32_3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb  

wget https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/cnijfilter-mp560series-32_3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-mp560series-32_3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Download and install the driver for **Canon PIXMA MP560 printer - scanning functionality** :

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/scangearmp-common-32_2.10-33~precise1_amd64.deb  
sudo dpkg -i scangearmp-common-32_2.10-33~precise1_amd64.deb

wget  https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/scangearmp-mp560series-32_2.10-33~precise1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i scangearmp-mp560series-32_2.10-33~precise1_amd64.deb
```

Alternatively download the original drivers from Canon Asia website and install them manually :

**Canon MP560 series IJ Printer Driver Version 3.20 for Linux (debian package archive)**

Download location : http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100236502.html

Extract the archive and install the packages by executing :

```
sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-common_3.20-1_i386.deb  
sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-mp560series_3.20-1_i386.deb
```

**Canon MP560 series ScanGear MP Version 1.40 for Linux (debian package archive)**

Download location : http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100237802.html

Extract the archive and install the packages by executing :

```
sudo dpkg -i scangearmp-common_1.40-1_i386.deb   
sudo dpkg -i scangearmp-mp560series_1.40-1_i386.deb
```

Sometimes it even works to select another printer from **Printers** setup in **System Settings**.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Asia drivers. I managed to get the driver installed, but I can't get the printer to print any test pages.  (The jobs show up in `lpq` but they don't ever complete. ) Regardless, I'm going to mark this as answered and put the non-working printer in a new question.

Comment: Oh, and one more quick thing: The 32-bit vs. 64 bit issue did get a little complicated. After fumbling around a little, a `sudo apt-get -f install ` got the necessary dependencies working.