# Canon Pixma printer on Ubuntu 15

Tags: printing, canon

Can't seem to get a printer working with my brand new 64-bit Ubuntu laptop.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

I see the printer, and everything looks fine, but then when I try to print a test page, the job enters a "held" state.

`lpq` shows all the print jobs as usual.
When I go to localhost:631 and check out the printer, I see the following message next to the job:

```
held since
Sun 20 Sep 2015 09:23:51 AM EDT 
"cannot load library"
```

Of course, it does not show *which* library is failing to load, because that would be a useful error message.
The driver looks like the right one.
Here's a cut-and paste of the printer description at the top of the screen:

```
Description:    Canon MP560
Location:   
Driver: Canon MP560 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10 (color, 2-sided printing)
Connection: cnijnet:/00-1E-8F-51-42-36
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=na_letter_8.5x11in sides=one-sided
```

I think this might be a 32-bit vs. 64-bit issue.
I installed the drivers from Canon Asia, as per [Install Canon MP560 Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675209/). Prior to the `dpkg` command, I ran

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I installed the packages, common first, then MP560. There were problems when I ran `sudo apt-get update`, so I fixed them with a `sudo apt-get -f install`.

That seemed to get everything working, but, as mentioned above, it just won't print. Running `sudo apt-get update` shows no broken dependencies.

Ideas, anyone? I'm soooooooo close to getting this to work that I just can't give up.

In `/var/log/cups/error_log.1`, I see a lot of these ...

```
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] Gutenprint: Reading 15300 6533
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] Printing page 1, 99%
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] ATTR: job-media-progress=99
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] Gutenprint: Reading 15300 6535
```

and then problems like this ...

```
E [19/Sep/2015:12:39:43 -0400] [Job 2] cannot load library
```

There is a lot of stuff in that log. Not sure what's really important. The last few lines of the file are

```
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] PID 2689 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/cnijnet) stopped with status 1.
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] Backend returned status 1 (failed)
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] time-at-completed=1442757771
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] End of messages
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] printer-state=3(idle)
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [20/Sep/2015:10:02:51 -0400] [Job 13] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Comment: Anything show in `dmesg` when pluggin the printer in, or in logs inside `/var/log/cups/`?

Comment: Will post a few messages in original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the instructions of post #10 of this [ubuntu forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1264928&p=8308515#post8308515):

1. download the driver from [canon-asia.com](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100236502.html)
2. unpack the archive with archive manager
3. use the following commands to install:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture cnijfilter-common_3.20-1_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture cnijfilter-mp560series_3.20-1_i386.deb
   ```

These are pretty much the same instructions as the [one over here](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/04/27/how-to-install-canon-printers-driver-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid-gnulinux-easy-guide/).

These are the 32bit drivers. You need to use the --force optionn to install on a 64 bit system. The rest of the aforementioned forum, covers the scanner driver.

Comment: The `--force-architecture` flag definitely seems like it may be the key to getting the right library in place. How do I handle the fact that tibtiff4 has gone away? I tried (naively) making a symlink to libitff5 in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`, but that didn't work.

Comment: I figured out the libtiff4 issue. See my answer below for details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I got it.

As Bogdan Willi correctly pointed out---thanks, BTW---my lack of the `--force-architecture` flag on the `dpkg` command pushed me into 32 bit / 64 purgatory.

By using the flag, I got an error message that the MP560 driver depends on `libtiff4`, which, helpfully, is no longer available.

I managed to find an old copy of this package ...

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.6-9ubuntu1.2_i386.deb
```

And I installed it ...

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture libtiff4_3.9.6-9ubuntu1.2_i386.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Et voila! The printer prints. I suspect that the mysterious "Unable to load library" messages were due to `libtiff4`. A better error message would have been great.

Anyway, thanks to everyone for helping out. It can be tough to figure out these issues without the exact hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly as above but on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS on my machine I needed the amd-64 version of libtiff4

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

wget http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/2/0100004692/01/cnijfilter-mg6300series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz

tar -xf ./cnijfilter-mg6300series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz
sudo ./install.sh
```

One note, if you are on a different network it won't find the printer. I work in a VM that is on its own network. I had to run the above on a computer connected to the correct network. Then I copied the lpadmin command that it used to register the printer and ran that on my VM.