# How can i install Canon PIXMA ip2772 Driver on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: printing

anybody know How can i install Canon PIXMA ip2772 Driver on ubuntu 14.04 ? or give me download link

Comment: Have you tried using your printer with the generic drivers (which come with Ubuntu)?

Comment: I've no this software, even i've  download from http://asiadrivers.com/pixma-ip2770-driver/ but  i can't install it

Comment: @EduardoCola was asking if you had actually tried to use the printer using the drivers Ubuntu provides.

Comment: Still i can't install it m when install it then show me error, An error occurred. A necessary package could not be found in the proper location.
otherwise how can i check it untill install it

Comment: Listen, what I'm asking is if you have already tried using your printer without installing anything. Ubuntu comes with a generic printer driver.

Comment: I can't found anything like as printer without install

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver)

Answer (score 0):

I am also using canon iP2772 . its basically plug and play. i just brought it , turned it on and that's it . nothing more. it shows it as 2700 series. did you try going to the printer option and see that if it is already connected?

[image]