# How to install canon lbp2900b printer in ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: printing

Based on few youtube vids and reddit posts i installed the canon CAPT drivers for my printer and executed the commands in termunal and got my printer to show up in the printer setting 
When i try to print a test page the status of the printer says processing data and sending data to priner but the printer doesn't print anything i am not the usual whirring noises at all

P.S. printer works on windows pc

Comment: so this needs the CAPT driver; so you need 4 phases: driver install; printer registration and (unlike other printers): you need to register it with the ccpd daemon; then to print, you need to start the ccpd daemon up; and the command is `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start` so if you set up the printer first time and it works; when you turn the computer off and start again, you need to issue the above command; by the way, is your system 64bit? I can offer a how to as a full answer; and perhaps best you delete the existing entry and we start afresh: what say you?

Comment: Yes it is a 64bit system

Comment: @pdc we can start a new thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver)

Answer (score 1):

so to install the driver for the LBP2900

1. get the driver from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html and you will be downloading linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz    ..it was updated 15th May 2017 so very up-to-date so please click to SAVE when you download and it should end up in your Downloads folder
2. open a terminal and paste these commands carefully one by one; and hit the ENTER key after each paste

   - `cd Downloads`

     ```
     tar -zxvf linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz       
     cd linux-capt-drv-v271-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian    
     sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb  
     sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb
     ```
3. Restart CUPS with `sudo service cups restart`
4. **register printer** with

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 –E
   ```
5. **Register the printer in the ccpd daemon setup file**.

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0
   ```

   - ..*and that assumes the 2900 is your only usb printer* ..
6. **Start ccpd daemon**.

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start
   ```

At that point, you should be able to print; please keep in touch and let us know how it goes ...

Comment: Is it works after system restart??

Comment: you have to issue the final command again; from a terminal; so if you open a terminal; press the up arrow on the numeric keyboard; the command should be there if it was the last used; and that will activate the ccpd daemon; otherwise google on how to automate it at startup

Comment: While executing point 4, I am getting error: "lpadmin: Unknown argument "–E"".
OS name: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
OS type: 64-bit