# How to connect to Canon lbp 2900 network printer in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, printing, canon

my canon LBP 2900 printer is connected to another pc in the network. It is possible to connect if it were a usb printer. How to connect to a network printer in ununtu 16.04?

Comment: Which version/flavor of Ubuntu are you using. What is the setup of the PC connected with the printer

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu this would help you see what you would need to do; so is the 2900 connected to another linux computer? My guess is you would need to install the CAPT driver on your computer too; assuming the CAPT driver is installed on the other computer ..

Comment: testing it, I see that if the LBP works via usb to one computer; that another computer; connected via network does NOT need CAPT drivers installed; one should be able to follow the ubuntu wiki above to help one set things up.

Comment: my ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS

Comment: the printer is not connected to a Linux computer, it is connected to a windows computer, I have CAPT driver on my computer, but does not work, may it is compatible with USB printers. I followed the instructions of this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/920841/how-to-install-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts