# Error installing Canon LBP 2900 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

[image: error image]

I've been trying to install Canon LBP 2900 driver on my Ubuntu 18.04 for the past few days. I tried following many tutorials such as [How to install canon lbp2900b printer in ubuntu 16.04 lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920841/how-to-install-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts), and also tried installing via GUI by downloading [this driver](https://www.canondriver.net/canon-lbp-2900-driver-linux/). I'm having problems installing.

```
Preparing to unpack cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cndrvcups-capt (2.71-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cndrvcups-capt:
cndrvcups-capt depends on cndrvcups-common (>= 3.21); however:
Version of cndrvcups-common on system is 2.60-1.

dpkg: error processing package cndrvcups-capt (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
cndrvcups-capt
```

How can I get this printer working?

Comment: You need to get correct versions of driver packages (see `cndrvcups-common (>= 3.21)` above) from Canon site or wherever you downloaded it.

Comment: You can download [`libpng12` from 16.04 LTS repository](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) and install it manually from terminal or with Gdebi.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following method will definitely help Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit users to install and use their Canon LBP2900 printer, which otherwise can be a harrowing experience for the less experienced.

It will NOT help to use the official Linux (32 bit or 64 bit) [LBP2900 driver from Canon](https://support-in.canon-asia.com/contents/IN/EN/0100459601.html)

Download the [Canon LBP2900 driver](https://github.com/agalakhov/captdriver) for 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 from [this page on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/agalakhov/captdriver/archive/master.zip).

Then run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt install build-essential git autoconf libtool libcups2-dev libcupsimage2-dev
git clone https://github.com/agalakhov/captdriver.git
cd captdriver
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
sudo cp src/rastertocapt /usr/lib/cups/filter/
```

(On some systems this might need to be `/usr/libexec/cups/filter`)

```
sudo cp Canon-LBP-2900.ppd /usr/share/ppd/custom/
```

Now open **Settings > Printers** and **Add Printer > USB printer**, selecting the driver *Canon LBP-2900 CAPT GDI printer, 0.1.0* from the list, and complete the remaining steps.

Then click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>. Print a test page and your Canon LBP2900 printer is ready to print on 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04!

Note: Sometimes, printing gets stuck with the message *Rendering completed*. In that case, it helped to just turn the printer off and on again.

Please report success or problems...

Comment: It helped. I was unable to select the driver from list, but there is an option to select custom PPD file as a driver - that way it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I selected driver from the list provided by OS - something for LBP2900

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall all the old versions of packages before you try to install new ones. Your message says: *cndrvcups-capt depends on cndrvcups-common (>= 3.21); however: Version of cndrvcups-common on system is 2.60-1.*

So remove them both then start again:

```
sudo dpkg --purge cndrvcups-common cndrvcups-capt
```

Answer (score 0):

so you need to go to the link that I gave in that other answer you referred to; the link you got the driver from is NOT an official Canon source; so best to avoid such links; do what I said in the other answer;