# How can I install canon mx360 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing

I try to get my Mx 360 working on 18.04. I got the driver downloaded from canon, extracted but there is no install.sh. What do I have to do?
In the meantime I managed to download the right driver from canons japanese site (http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100329501.html). I even got through these Tutorial (https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/04/21/printer-canon-mx360-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-how-to-download-install/)  but now the software will not detect my printer anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver)

Answer (score 0):

so from the Canon Singapore site that you cite;

I get **cnijfilter-mx360series-3.50-1-deb.tar.gz** downloaded and saved

if you open a terminal and copy the commands below and do

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mx360series-3.50-1-deb.tar.gz

cd cnijfilter-mx360series-3.50-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

does that not run an install script for you?

Comment: Yes, the install script is running perfectly until it demands to conect the device which will not be found. I didn't change the cable, the port or even moved/touched my printer. I just upgraded to 18.04. (by the way, my Epson V330 scanner also doesn't work as well as my internal VPN connection to the other computer, K9Copy gives messages, and my 'fritzbox' - my internet-modem- firstly denies the whole connection, Clementine is denying my USB Port (Stick) and VCL is always shutting down the moment i try to play DVD's)