# CANON G2012 Driver Problem

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Recently I bought a canon pixma G2012 printer without knowing the fact that there is no driver for the series!!! Can someone help me out? I tried with gutenprint as suggested by some of the forums, but didn't succeed either. It seems that a .ppd file is needed for the cup-based printing which I couldn't figure out! Please help!!!

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What have you tried so far? Where and how have you searched for the driver? Please [edit] your question to include the information. Related (but outdated): [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver)

Comment: I haven't been able to find a driver for g2012 as well.

Answer (score 1):

After connecting printer to PC through usb cable just click on add printer option which you should get within devices  or you can just search  using key word printer
 after that just click on add option and then select the printer and then click on add
this should work for you for printing jobs.

this is for the person who are using ubuntu

Comment: Doesn't help with the specific model mentioned g2012.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your Pc and printer through your cable and turn on the printer, after that, your pc will automatically detect the driver for the connected device. I'm using Linux ubuntu 18.04 and it works fine. But, for the purpose of scanning any document, you might need to install some software(I haven't tried yet).

Comment: Doesn't help with the specific model mentioned g2012.