# Canon MFC Printer (ethernet) discovered but won't print Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: 20.04, ethernet, canon

The status reported is:

Idle - No suitable destination host found by cups-browsed.

Device URI implicitclass://Canon_MF642C_643C_644C_c9_4d_a4_/

Not sure what else is relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by downloading the latest drivers (from Canon Asia)
http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/?personal

Apologies but I can't find the answer with the added info about installing. If I find it I'll add it here.